# merge attributes of 3 different variables into one in cloudera sql

Tags: sql, cloudera-cdh

I would like to merge / move all the appointment reasons  from:

appointment2
appointment3
appointment4
appointment5
appointment6

into appointment1

How can this be archived in Cloudera sql ?

What would be the solution to make sure not two 'reasons' clash - in other words if there is a note on appointment3 and appointment4 -  I would need to create a column appointment1b to make sure I don't lose any information. 
How can this be done?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want coalesce?

```
select coalesce(appointment2, appointment3, appointment4, appointment5, appointment6) as appointment1
```

Comment: It works, thanks! What happens when appointment 2 and appointment 3 both have a note. Can I build a condition that a new variable should be created to take care of both notes?

Comment: @Anna . . . Ask another question, and provide clear sample data and desired results.